# will child have its own field variable or share its parent variable through inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to consult an issue about Java field variable inheritance. Here is the code segment:

```
//parent
public class Parent {
    protected int a = 0;
}

//son
public class Son extends Parent{
    public void demo(){
        a = 1;
        System.out.println(super.a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Son son = new Son();
        son.demo();
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
```

expect:

```
0
```

In my code the child will inherit field variable `a`, and we called it `sonA` and the field variable `a` of parent called `parentA`.

My question is whether `sonA` and `parentA`  the same one (e.g there address is 0x1234)? or they represent two different variable (e.g. one address 0x1234 another 0x5678)?

Comment: Yes, they're the same variable. Is that all?

Comment: Yes it's a same one.  You can call base class method or variable implicitly or explicitly, it depends.  That's it.

Comment: There is no `sonA` in your code. Could you possibly take the time and trouble to spell 'field' correctly? And compose a tittle that makes sense? And not use code formatting for text that isn't code? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP my question is subclass object will have its own filed variable or share the parent variable through inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They share the same address, however you did overwrite the default value `0` with `1` so it's correct behaviour. Let's check that:

```
Son son = new Son();
Parent parent = new Parent();
Field fieldAParent = parent.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
Field fieldA = son.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
```

You'll get an exception on the last line, because class son doesn't contain field `a`

Answer (score 0):

It's the same one, because `Son` doesn't have an `a` of its own. If you introduce one, you'll hide `Parent`'s `a` and then you'll see the behaviour you're expecting:

```
//parent
public class Parent {
    protected int a = 0;
}

//son
public class Son extends Parent{
    int a = 0; // this hides the Parent field

    public void demo(){
        a = 1; // this accesses the Son field
        System.out.println(super.a); // this accesses the Parent field explicitly
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Son son = new Son();
        son.demo();
    }
}
```

However, this would generally not be a recommended practice, as it could lead to a lot of confusion.